# How to convert UK grid to coordinates in PostgreSQL?

Tags: qgis, postgresql, sql

I have a very large file with UK grid references that I need to get coordinates from

I'm on a Mac so I cant seem to use the solution provided in this link https://digimap.edina.ac.uk/webhelp/os/data_information/os_data_issues/ng_converter.htm

Furthermore, since it's too large of a file, I can't just copy the entire grid column onto a txt file.

I was thinking the best solution would just be to import the whole file onto the database and hope that there's some function that will do this.

They look like the following:

[image]

Comment: what do your grid references look like? what sort of coordinates do you want?

Comment: @IanTurton I think he wants to convert the XY123456 to numeric X,Y values.

Comment: @IanTurton hi again. I wanted to convert to 27700 but WGS84 is fine too. Just need a set of coordinates that i can work with

Comment: The OS publish excel conversion functions here if that is of use to you: [https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/documents/resources/maptile-gridref-conversion.xlsm](https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/documents/resources/maptile-gridref-conversion.xlsm)

Comment: @JimT I'm clearly not an excel pro but is there a way I can copy their formula onto my spreadsheet? I just tried it and it returned #NAME

Comment: There are two functions, `GridRef_to_Northings` and `GridRef_to_Eastings`.  The code for these is in visual basic and is stored within the spreadsheet under the _developer_ menu.   You'd likely be better off copying your data into the OS sheet.

Comment: @JimT what menu? all i see is 2 tables and a map

Comment: to enable the Excel developer tab: [https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/questions/developer_tab2013.php](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/questions/developer_tab2013.php)

Comment: @JimT I think i did it? I copied the module to my sheet and it's currently calculating (though it's very slow and it actually might take far too long)

Comment: Not a PostgreSQL solution, but have you tried using batch convert in www.gridreferencefinder.com? You may need to break the file into parts depending on size though.

Comment: @ferus89 I didnt find a button to upload my csv. breaking it down is not a good solution since there are too many rows

Comment: I should have another look at 'ng converter', if you go to the link you posted you'll see that it is also available as a Perl script. I would have thought that Perl was available for the Mac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OSGB national grid uses nested 5x5 squares and two sets of digits to provide a location (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordnance_Survey_National_Grid#Grid_digits):

```
For example, the grid reference of the 100 m square containing the summit of 
Ben Nevis is NN 166 712. (Grid references may be written with or without spaces;
e.g., also NN166712.) NN has an easting of 200 km and northing of 700 km, so the
OSGB36 National Grid location for Ben Nevis is at 216600, 771200.
```

The following link has an example of code to convert from e.g. NN166712 to 216600, 771200 https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-os-gridref.html

```
create table letters (id serial primary key, letters varchar(2), 
                      x int, y int);
-- add the valid letters for the main squares
insert into letters (letters) values (
    unnest(array['SV', 'SQ', 'SL', 'SF', 'SA', 'NV', 'NQ', 'NL', 'NF',
                 'NA', 'HV', 'HQ', 'HL', 'SW', 'SR', 'SM', 'SG', 'SB', 
                 'NW', 'NR', 'NM', 'NG', 'NB', 'HW', 'HR', 'HM', 'SX',
                 'SS', 'SN', 'SH', 'SC', 'NX', 'NS', 'NN', 'NH', 'NC',
                 'HX', 'HS', 'HN', 'SY', 'ST', 'SO', 'SJ', 'SD', 'NY',
                 'NT', 'NO', 'NJ', 'ND', 'HY', 'HT', 'HO', 'SZ', 'SU',
                 'SP', 'SK', 'SE', 'NZ', 'NU', 'NP', 'NK', 'NE', 'HZ',
                 'HU', 'HP', 'TV', 'TQ', 'TL', 'TF', 'TA', 'OV', 'OQ', 
                 'OL', 'OF', 'OA', 'JV', 'JQ', 'JL', 'TW', 'TR', 'TM',
                 'TG', 'TB', 'OW', 'OR', 'OM', 'OG', 'OB', 'JW', 'JR', 
                 'JM' ]));
-- set the basic x and y values
update letters set x = 8, y = 8 where left(letters,1) = 'H';
update letters set x = 9, y = 9 where left(letters,1) = 'J';
update letters set x = 13, y = 13 where left(letters,1) = 'N';
update letters set x = 14, y = 14 where left(letters,1) = 'O';
update letters set x = 18, y = 18 where left(letters,1) = 'S';
update letters set x = 19, y = 19 where left(letters,1) = 'T';
-- ToDo - multiply x, y, value by 100000 and add offset
-- Grid:
-- ABCDE
-- FGHJK -- No I
-- LMNOP
-- QRSTU
-- VWXYZ
-- A|F|L|Q|V -- x offset 0, y offset 0
-- B|G|M|R|W -- offset 20000, y offset 0
```

Then set up a query to split the NN166712 into 'NN', 166::integer, 712::integer and generate your grid value.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick Java translation of the OS visual basic code from the [spread sheet](https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/documents/resources/maptile-gridref-conversion.xlsm) mentioned in the comments.

```
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.Coordinate;
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.GeometryFactory;
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.Point;

public class OSGridref {
  static GeometryFactory GF = new GeometryFactory();
  static String[][] gridLetters = { { "SV", "SQ", "SL", "SF", "SA", "NV", "NQ", "NL", "NF", "NA", "HV", "HQ", "HL" },
      { "SW", "SR", "SM", "SG", "SB", "NW", "NR", "NM", "NG", "NB", "HW", "HR", "HM" },
      { "SX", "SS", "SN", "SH", "SC", "NX", "NS", "NN", "NH", "NC", "HX", "HS", "HN" },
      { "SY", "ST", "SO", "SJ", "SD", "NY", "NT", "NO", "NJ", "ND", "HY", "HT", "HO" },
      { "SZ", "SU", "SP", "SK", "SE", "NZ", "NU", "NP", "NK", "NE", "HZ", "HU", "HP" },
      { "TV", "TQ", "TL", "TF", "TA", "OV", "OQ", "OL", "OF", "OA", "JV", "JQ", "JL" },
      { "TW", "TR", "TM", "TG", "TB", "OW", "OR", "OM", "OG", "OB", "JW", "JR", "JM" } };

  static public Point convertGridRef(String gridref) {
    String ref = gridref.toUpperCase();

    int easting = getEasting(ref);
    int northing = getNorthing(ref);
    return GF.createPoint(new Coordinate(easting, northing));
  }

  /**
   * @param first
   * @param second
   */
  public static int getEasting(String ref) {

    char first = ref.charAt(0);
    if (first != 'H' && first != 'J' && first != 'N' && first != 'O' && first != 'S' && first != 'T') {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid grid reference starting letter " + ref);
    }
    char second = ref.charAt(1);
    if (second < 65 || second > 90 || second == 'I') {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid grid reference second letter " + ref);
    }
    int len = ref.length();
    if (len < 2 || len > 12 || len % 2 != 0) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid grid reference wrong length " + ref);
    }
    boolean quadExists = false;
    String quad = "";
    if (len > 6 && (ref.endsWith("SW") || ref.endsWith("NW") || ref.endsWith("NE") || ref.endsWith("SE"))) {
      quadExists = true;
      quad = ref.substring(len - 2);
    }
    String numbs = ref;

    if (!quadExists && len > 2) {
      numbs = ref.substring(2);
    } else if (quadExists) {
      numbs = ref.substring(2, len - 2);
    }
    if (len > 2) {
      double coords;
      try {
        coords = Double.parseDouble(numbs);
      } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("bad numeric format in " + ref, e);
      }
    }

    // convert to a coordinate

    String hundreds = Character.toString(first) + Character.toString(second);
    boolean match = false;
    int easting1st = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++) {
      for (int y = 0; y < 12; y++) {
        if (gridLetters[x][y].equalsIgnoreCase(hundreds)) {
          easting1st = x;
          match = true;
        }
      }
    }
    if (!match)
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid tile square " + hundreds);
    String eastings;
    int lenNum = numbs.length();

    switch (len) {
    case 2:
      // 100km square
      return 100_000 * easting1st;
    case 4:
      // 10km Square
      eastings = Integer.toString(easting1st) + numbs.substring(0, lenNum / 2);
      try {
        return Integer.parseInt(eastings) * 10_000;
      } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("bad numeric format in " + ref, e);
      }
    case 6:
      // 5 or 1km square
      String qDigit = "";
      if ("SW".equalsIgnoreCase(quad) || "NW".equalsIgnoreCase(quad)) {
        qDigit = "0";
      } else if ("SE".equalsIgnoreCase(quad) || "NE".equalsIgnoreCase(quad)) {
        qDigit = "5";
      }
      eastings = Integer.toString(easting1st) + numbs.substring(0, lenNum / 2) + qDigit;
      try {
        return Integer.parseInt(eastings) * 1000;
      } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("bad numeric format in " + ref, e);
      }
    case 8:
      // 500 or 100m square
      qDigit = "";
      if ("SW".equalsIgnoreCase(quad) || "NW".equalsIgnoreCase(quad)) {
        qDigit = "0";
      } else if ("SE".equalsIgnoreCase(quad) || "NE".equalsIgnoreCase(quad)) {
        qDigit = "5";
      }
      eastings = Integer.toString(easting1st) + numbs.substring(0, lenNum / 2) + qDigit;
      try {
        return Integer.parseInt(eastings) * 100;
      } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("bad numeric format in " + ref, e);
      }
    case 10:
      // 10m square
      eastings = numbs.substring(0, lenNum / 2);
      try {
        return Integer.parseInt(eastings) * 10;
      } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("bad numeric format in " + ref, e);
      }
    case 12:
      // 1m square
      eastings = numbs.substring(0, lenNum / 2);
      try {
        return Integer.parseInt(eastings);
      } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("bad numeric format in " + ref, e);
      }
    default:
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unexpected input in getEasting " + ref);
    }
  }

  public static int getNorthing(String ref) {
    char first = ref.charAt(0);
    if (first != 'H' && first != 'J' && first != 'N' && first != 'O' && first != 'S' && first != 'T') {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid grid reference starting letter " + ref);
    }
    char second = ref.charAt(1);
    if (second < 65 || second > 90 || second == 'I') {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid grid reference second letter " + ref);
    }
    int len = ref.length();
    if (len < 2 || len > 12 || len % 2 != 0) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid grid reference wrong length " + ref);
    }
    boolean quadExists = false;
    String quad = "";
    if (len > 6 && (ref.endsWith("SW") || ref.endsWith("NW") || ref.endsWith("NE") || ref.endsWith("SE"))) {
      quadExists = true;
      quad = ref.substring(len - 2);
    }
    String numbs = ref;

    if (!quadExists && len > 2) {
      numbs = ref.substring(2);
    } else if (quadExists) {
      numbs = ref.substring(2, len - 2);
    }
    if (len > 2) {
      double coords;
      try {
        coords = Double.parseDouble(numbs);
      } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("bad numeric format in " + ref, e);
      }
    }

    // convert to a coordinate

    String hundreds = Character.toString(first) + Character.toString(second);
    boolean match = false;
    int northing1st = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++) {
      for (int y = 0; y < 12; y++) {
        if (gridLetters[x][y].equalsIgnoreCase(hundreds)) {
          northing1st = y;
          match = true;
        }
      }
    }
    if (!match)
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid tile square " + hundreds);
    String northings;
    int lenNum = numbs.length();

    switch (len) {
    case 2:
      // 100km square
      return 100_000 * northing1st;
    case 4:
      // 10km Square
      northings = Integer.toString(northing1st) + numbs.substring(lenNum / 2);
      try {
        return Integer.parseInt(northings) * 10_000;
      } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("bad numeric format in " + ref, e);
      }
    case 6:
      // 5 or 1km square
      String qDigit = "";
      if ("SW".equalsIgnoreCase(quad) || "SE".equalsIgnoreCase(quad)) {
        qDigit = "0";
      } else if ("NW".equalsIgnoreCase(quad) || "NE".equalsIgnoreCase(quad)) {
        qDigit = "5";
      }
      northings = Integer.toString(northing1st) + numbs.substring(lenNum / 2) + qDigit;
      try {
        return Integer.parseInt(northings) * 1000;
      } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("bad numeric format in " + ref, e);
      }
    case 8:
      // 500 or 100m square
      qDigit = "";
      if ("SW".equalsIgnoreCase(quad) || "NW".equalsIgnoreCase(quad)) {
        qDigit = "0";
      } else if ("SE".equalsIgnoreCase(quad) || "NE".equalsIgnoreCase(quad)) {
        qDigit = "5";
      }
      northings = Integer.toString(northing1st) + numbs.substring(lenNum / 2) + qDigit;
      try {
        return Integer.parseInt(northings) * 100;
      } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("bad numeric format in " + ref, e);
      }
    case 10:
      // 10m square
      northings = numbs.substring(lenNum / 2);
      try {
        return Integer.parseInt(northings) * 10;
      } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("bad numeric format in " + ref, e);
      }
    case 12:
      // 1m square
      northings = numbs.substring(lenNum / 2);
      try {
        return Integer.parseInt(northings);
      } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("bad numeric format in " + ref, e);
      }
    default:
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unexpected input in getEasting " + ref);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried any tool which converts your coordinates? Here you have an example: https://www.asturnatura.com/sinflac/calculadora-conversiones-coordenadas.php
Good luck.

Comment: This is not related to my question at all